# how to use java script to create new div's inside an existing div?

Tags: javascript, css, html

The page i am making is designed to:

1. take the dimensions of a set of tiles and a wall then print out how many tiles are needed to fill the area of the wall
2. print on screen a visual representation of what the wall will look like with the tiles on.

so far i've managed to successfully complete the first part.

```
<style>
#wallspace {
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin:auto;
}
</style>

<form >

   Tile Dimensions<br />

   Width: <input type="text" id="tile_width" />cm

   height: <input type="text" id="tile_height" />cm 

   <br />
   Wall Dimensions<br />
   Width: <input type="text" id="wall_width" />cm

    height:<input type="text" id="wall_height" />cm


   </form> 
   <button onclick="createWall()" >Try it</button>
   <p id="result">  </p> 
   <div id="wallspace">
   </div>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function createWall() {
//collect dimensions from user input
var tileWidth = document.getElementById("tile_width").value;
var tileHeight = document.getElementById("tile_height").value;
var wallWidth = document.getElementById("wall_width").value;
var wallHeight = document.getElementById("wall_height").value;
//find the areas of the tile and the wall
var tileArea = tileWidth * tileHeight;
var wallArea = wallWidth * wallHeight;
//divide these to find the number of tiles needed 
var noOfTiles = (wallArea/tileArea);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="number of tiles needed are " +            
noOfTiles;
}
</script>
```

Now when it comes to printing the wall, I was trying to use a nested for loop to print the tiles. As below:

```
function printTiles()
{  
var tileWidth = document.getElementById("tile_width").value;
var tileHeight = document.getElementById("tile_height").value;
var wallWidth = document.getElementById("wall_width").value;
var wallHeight = document.getElementById("wall_height").value;
//rows
for (var i = 0; i < wallHeight; i = i + tileHeight)
{ 
  //collumns
  for (var a = 0; a < wallWidth; a = a + tileWidth)
  {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.width = tileWidth + "px";
    div.style.height = tileHeight + "px";
    div.style.cssFloat = "left";
    div.style.borderWidth = "2px";
    div.style.borderStyle = "solid";

    div.innerHTML = i;
    document.getElementById("wallspace").appendChild(div); 
   }
}
```

so the nested for loop would print each column on the row than go to the next row so on.
For some reason my printTiles is not working at all and i dont understand why? secondly, when i get it working can i simply use

```
document.getElementById("wallspace").innerHTML=printTiles();
```

Leave a comment if you don't understand what i'm trying to do and i'll try to explain it better.

Answer (score 2):

You are appending your DIV to itself with this line:

```
div.appendChild(div);
```

What you should be doing is something like this:

```
document.getElementById("wallspace").appendChild(div);
```

Also, your `printTiles()` function has no way of knowing what `wallWidth`, `tileWidth`, `wallHeight` and `tileHeight` are, as they are declared inside of `createWall()`. You might need to either combine these functions or add these lines to the beginning of `printTiles()`:

```
var tileWidth = document.getElementById("tile_width").value;
var tileHeight = document.getElementById("tile_height").value;
var wallWidth = document.getElementById("wall_width").value;
var wallHeight = document.getElementById("wall_height").value;
```

Comment: thanks for your help , ive now managed to print out some tiles that are the correct size in pixels, but a seemingly random amount of them ill update my code in the question , thanks again !